# Retrieving data with many jsonp requests

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsonp, react-dom

My question is how retrieve data using many jsonp requests? it is practical? Currently, I'm using in my CRA this fragment of code (below)(pseudocode).

```
import * as fetch from 'fetch-jsonp';
import * as BlueBird from 'bluebird'; // bluebird is promise library

const getData = async () => {
  const urls = ['https://...', 'https://...'] // containt about 20000 urls
  const response = await BlueBird.map(urls, url => fetch(url), { concurrency: 10 })
  return response
}
```

Working version of code creates script tags in my DOM, so as you can guess it prolongs DOM rendering, my laptop starts really heating and I end up getting error "render process gone" (on small data everything works). So what I should do? move my code to the server side and use json? or it's possible to create separate react dom and use it for jsonp? (cannot use json on client side cause cors)

Answer (score -1):

Use jsoup official dependency if you are working for Android or library for java.
Then use

```
String html="here html";
Document doc=Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question. Did you confuse JSONP with Jsoup? They have similar names but are completely different things.